# Entity Framework Core: One-Way Navigation Property without a Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

My class configuration looks like this:

```cs
class Item {
  Guid ParentId { get; set; }
  // ... 
}

class ClassWithItemCollectionA {
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
  // ...
}

class ClassWithItemCollectionB {
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

I would like to populate `ClassWithItemCollectionA.Items` and `ClassWithItemCollectionB.Items` navigation properties joining the entities with `Item.ParentId -> ClassWithItemCollectionA.Id` and `Item.ParentId -> ClassWithItemCollectionB.Id`.

I have tried with different approaches, but I've ended up getting undesirable results.

- If I let EF Core create the navigation properties it creates an extra column for every entity type I add an `Item` collection to.
- If I force EF Core to use ParentId as foreign key it creates the database schema without extra columns, but creates extra constraints that prevent me from inserting anything in the `Item` table.
- I could make `Items` collection unmapped and do an extra query to populate it for every `ClassWithItemCollectionX`, incurring into the N+1 problem.

Is there any way to define a base class like this:

```cs
class BaseClassWithItemCollection {
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then specify how to retrieve the `Items` collection, or any other way to achive what I'm looking for?

Comment: Remove the ParentId, it's useless as you wont know what entity type it's referring to. Alternatively you could refactor to implement "Table-per-Hierarchy" as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: The reason for ParentId to be exposed is to have a way to append Items to a generic entity. These "ClassWithItemCollectionX" are just special cases for which I want to include the Items directly without an extra query. Since these entities are highly heterogeneous the TPH approach doesn't seem ideal either. :(